# How to get the full SQL query in Application Insights

Tags: azure, entity-framework-6, azure-application-insights, .net-4.7.2

I just watched the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TV1u6UoBRwk and saw the section on End to End transactions.
I've used that to track down a SQL query that is taking 1.8 mins.

The query is truncated (probably because EF is generating a super long query).

Is there any way to get the full query from Application Insights?
[image]

Comment: Have you Enabled [SqlCommands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5g7e.png) in `App Service` => `Application Insights`

Comment: What is the framework of the application you are using?

Comment: @Harshitha Yes I've enabled SqlCommands, otherwise it wouldn't be showing the generated SQL query. The issue is that it's truncated, not that it's not showing the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- By default, SQL Collection is set to off. We need to enable it in the Azure Portal.
- To get the full SQL Query, we need to enable the `SQL Commands` in our deployed `App Service` => `Application Insights`.

[image]

- Add the below line of code in `Program.cs`  file, if it is `.NET Core` Applications.

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });
```

- If it is `.NET Framework` Application, add the below line in `TelemetryModules` section in `ApplicationInsights.config` file (which is generated when we add Application Insights in Visual Studio.

```cs
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">, 
<EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>true</EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>
</Add>
```

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query) and [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/28).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I'm using .NET Framework.

Comment: As mentioned above ,for .net Framework please add the `EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation` in ApplicationInsights.config file.